# Modify existing cmd commands

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to modify existing cmd commands, both to change out the code to another batch file and to modify the code.

For example, when I type "calc" it opens the calculator app but I want it to open a batch script I made, and when I want to edit the "help" screen. How can I modify the code that runs when I type in existing cmd commands such as tree, help and calc?

Comment: This doens't seem like a programming related question, but then again, I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean to begin with. `change out the code to another batch file and to modify the code` - care to explain this?

Comment: Well then you need to either rename the executables, or you need to write local batch files with different names, that being said, I do not know what the reason would be that you want to do this. Anyway, this question is off topic to be honest.

Comment: See https://ss64.com/nt/path.html

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to replace or modify all exiting programs and/or scripts, but you can "trick" your Windows to prioritize / execute yours that are similarly named.

When you type "calc" in the command prompt, you will effectively execute the file:

**C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe**

[image]

You need to look at the Environmental Variable named "Path"; this is where you identify which directories should be seen by your system as "global". Any EXE, BAT or CMD you'll try to execute will look at the current directory first; and if it isn't found it will try to find it in the directories listed in "Path".

For example. Lets say you want to run your own file called help.exe; a console app that you created.

1. Create a folder e.g. **C:\CustomBatchFiles**.
2. Go to your computer's **Advanced System Settings**.
3. Go to **Environmental Variables**

You should see the following screen:
[image]

4. Under "System Variables", find the one called "Path", then "Edit".
5. Add the folder in which your custom scripts / batch files reside. Please be aware that new entries will be added to the bottom - and this list dictates the "priority" - so, once created, push the "Move Up" button until your directory is at the very top.

[image]

6. Click OK, and OK again to apply this new change. You might have to reboot your system; or at the very least re - open your command prompt.
7. From there you should be able to execute your commands no matter which directory is currently open, including "used" ones such as calc and help.

Here's a tiny program I wrote. I compiled it as help.exe, and copied it to the directory that I added as a Path (**C:\CustomBatchFiles**):

```
    class Help
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start executing your program / script from here.");
        }
    }
```

It will produce the following output:

[image]